# Do drop attacks reoccur?

Tags: dizziness, equilibrium-balance, frequency, inner-ear

I'm doing some research on drop attacks, specifically for those causes mentioned on http://american-hearing.org/disorders/drop-attacks/

I would like to get an idea of the frequency for drop attacks for each of the known causes mentioned in that article.  Some suggestions for possible responses could be:

- X times in a lifetime
- X times per year (or month or week, etc.)
- 100% unpredictable
- More frequent in older/younger/gender/etc  people (how frequent in each?)
- No information available

If possible, provide a reference to where you get your information.  Here are the causes listed on the page I linked to:

1) Cause never established

2) Due to the heart (a variant of syncope)

3) Poor circulation to the brain

4) Problems with both the heart and the brain

5) Seizures

6) Due to the inner ear

7) Psychological problems

Comment: We can't diagnose you or tell you if it will recur or not. It's simply not possible for anyone on the internet to answer your question.

Comment: I agree with your comment, and sorry: I guess my question was too specific.  I didn't want a diagnoses; I'm just wondering if drop attacks tend to reoccur or generally are a one-time thing.  For example: tourette syndrome tends to get milder or go away with age. But no where on the internet can I find documentation as to whether ANY drop attack reoccurs ever, regardless of the diagnoses, and if so, how often (twice in a lifetime, once per week, etc.).  Perhaps some are sporadic, some are a one time event and some are frequent?  I can't find any info on the internet.

Comment: I have completely redone the question, I hope that makes it more answerable.

Comment: Much better, thank you. I retracted my downvote and close vote.

Comment: Some drops will typically reoccur, such as in epilepsy or postural hypotension. Others - it depends: vasovagal syncope - you may experience it once or --if you are prone to it -- often. Are you looking for the actual official *statistics* or just for the *pattern* aka random, sporadic, episodic..? And do you need to publish this or is it for personal use?

Comment: You may want to include postural hypotension, vasovagal syncope and hypoglycemia in diabetics as additional causes.

Comment: Carey - thank you.  I'm glad it's more clear now.  Jan - I would love to have official statistics if they are available (although my categories might have to change since official statistics might not fit into them, but that would be fine).  Otherwise the general pattern would be sufficient to answer the question.  This is just for personal use, I'm not planning on publishing anything.  Once I get back on a computer I'll update my question to reflect those replies, and add in your suggested causes as well.